# Beaglebone Black: Video capture & Object Detection Same Time?

Tags: linux, video-processing, beagleboneblack

I am well aware that the BBB is capable of doing both of these operations separately, however can anyone speculate whether it would be possible to do both HD video capturing and realtime Object Detection simultaneously?

I guess the only real way to know is to check, but I'm curious if anyone else has gotten this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after testing, it can, but without doing some hacking to the openCV code, the capture rate and framerate of the video must be the same (could also be due to settings on my webcam limiting functionality), thus it is not that viable afaik since rates will be <10 fps.